# How can I wait for refresh element by locator?

Tags: element, wait, robotframework

I have element on the page and further actions I can do only when it was refreshed.

How can I track it? Or refresh it forcibly?

Comment: What do you mean by "refreshed"? When the page refreshes? When the element text changes? When the DOM element is destroyed and recreated?

Comment: How would the user know when they could interact with the page or part of it?

Comment: @BryanOakley, Page does not refresh. The DOM is recreated.
I can not use Wait Until Element Is Visible or Wait Until Page Contains, because I don't know will be this element there or not. I need to check this, but after recreate DOM for element

Comment: @ombre42, user sees list of elements and see when it update.

Comment: If checking for the cue that a user would use to know the data is refreshed is not feasible, you could attach an element to the part of the DOM that will be replaced using Execute Javascript. Then you could use Wait Until Page Does Not Contain Element to wait for your injected element to disappear.